# Do We Inherit a Interface or Implements an Interface?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, interface

Well till now I knew we implement interfaces , but today some body (you know who , i guess)) told me that If I write a interface then we implement it in class , but if it is a system Interface , Let's say `INotifyPropertyChanged` , the we call it Class A inherits Interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Though I feel right , I am not sure and unsure how to explain it to him.

I need to specify in my Design doucment . So wondering what shall I mention, Inherit or Implemet.

Comment: Part of the confusion stems from c++ lacking `interface` that is distinct from `class`. Users of Java will be able to point out their differences.

Comment: This is really a C# question, but as other have said you implement an interface. This is done by inheriting from it.

Comment: helpful question I found is here http://stackoverflow.com/q/8531292/1055241

Answer (score 5):

We inherit it to implement it. What's the problem?

Comment: I need to specify in my Design doucment . So wondering what shall I mention, Inherit or Implemet.

Comment: @user443144: implementing. Inheritance is a detail of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

1-Interface is implemented by a class whether is it a normal interface or system interface.

2- One Interface can inherit another interface.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking language-independant you would say "`implementing an interface`". The symbol in UML names it the same (there is a special implementing-arrow which is used for interfaces instead of the inheriting-arrow)
Anybody understanding UML would understand what you're meaning.

In C++ you have to consider that there aren't interfaces as they exist in other languages. A interface is a pure virtual class.
So classes which "use" this interface are strictly speaking inheriting from a pure virtual class.
If you're saying "`MyClass inherits the pure virtual class IClass`" someone C++-related would understand that you mean interface I think. He also would understand if you say "`MyClass is implementing IClass`" and in background think of a pure virtual class.

Answer (score 0):

If Class A provides the method bodies (that is, code) for the methods that are declared in the interface, then Class A is implementing the interface.

In C++, because of the lack of distinction between interface and class, the source code syntax for inheriting from a class and implementing an interface is the same. Hence the confusion.